# Query posts with custom field is array

Tags: wordpress

I'm using ACF to create custom field of select type. I used like this to create custom select field like this:

```
1 : Anh
2 : Hai
3 : Hoang
4 : May
....
12 : Lan
```

I use this query to search posts have value is 1 (Anh) like this:

```
                 URL for query :   /?thename=1
                 $thename = $_GET['thename'];
                 $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'interviews',
                            'post_status'    => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => $perpage,
                            'paged'          => get_query_var('paged'),
                            'meta_query'    => array(
                                    'key'       => 'thename',
                                    'value'     => $thename,
                                    'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                                )
```

I searched like this but it returns wrong results. I think the value of `thename` field is array (value and label) then It is not possible to use query above.

So can you suggest me to do with this search? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your meta query should be an array within an array... update the `meta_query` like below:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'thename',
        'value'     => $thename,
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [meta_query documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/) meta_query must **contains one or more arrays**, so your query must be something look like this :

```
'meta_query' => [
  [
    'key'       => 'thename',
    'value'     => $thename,
    'compare'   => 'LIKE',
  ]
]
```